# Let $a\in \mathbb Z$ be such that $a=b^2+c^2,$ where $b,c\in \mathbb Z-\{0\}.$ Then $a$ can be written as ...

Tags: elementary-number-theory, examples-counterexamples

> Let $a\in \mathbb Z$ be such that $a=b^2+c^2,$ where $b,c\in \mathbb
>  Z-\{0\}.$ Then $a$ can be written as
>
> $(1)pd^2,$ where $d\in \mathbb Z$ and $p$ is a prime with
> $p\equiv1\pmod  4$
>
> $(2)pd^2,$ where $d\in \mathbb Z$ and $p$ is a prime with
> $p\equiv3\pmod  4$
>
> $(3)pqd^2,$ where $d\in \mathbb Z$ and $p,q$ are primes with
> $p\equiv1,\pmod  4$,$q\equiv3\pmod  4$
>
> $(4)pqd^2,$ where $d\in \mathbb Z$ and $p,q$ are distinct primes with
> $p,q\equiv3\pmod  4$

**Counter-Example for option 2**

$5=2^2+1^2$ but $5\not\equiv 3(mod 4)$

**Counter-Example for option 3**

$25=3^2+4^2,25=5.5.1^2,5\equiv1(mod4)$ but $5\not\equiv3(mod4)$

> What is the explicit counterexample for option (4)?
>
> Also,how to prove option (1)?

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of your "counterexamples". Option $2$, for example asserts  that there is no natural number, expressible as the sum of two squares, of the form $pd^2$ with $p\equiv 3\pmod 4$.  It does not assert that *all* natural numbers, expressible as the sum of two squares, must take that form.  So...producing an example like $5$ doesn't prove anything.

Comment: You could, however, use $5$ as a counterexample to option $1$. Indeed,  $5$ is an example which contradicts option $1$, so we see that option $1$ is false.

Comment: @lulu:but,5 can be expressed as $5.1^2$ and $5\equiv 1\pmod 4$...how can it be counterexample?

Comment: The claim behind option $1$ is that if $a\in \mathbb N$  can be written as $b^2+c^2$ for natural numbers $b,c$ then $a$ *cannnot* be written as $pd^2$ where $p\equiv 1 \pmod 4$.  To see that $5$ is a counterexample to that claim, note that $5=1^2+2^2$ and $5=5\times 1^2$ where $5\equiv 1 \pmod 4$.  Thus option $1$ is False.

Comment: @lulu:I've changed the question,please note it...I've replaced "cannot " with "can"

Comment: Post edit, now none of those options are correct and you should easily be able to produce counterexamples to each of them.  The original version made more sense.

Comment: @lulu:in order to make the "unique" option to be correct ,i done it so

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  In any case, all those options are incorrect.  A single counterexample works for all of them...$5\times 13\times 17=24^2+23^2$ for one.

Comment: @lulu: in the answer key ,it is given that $a$ can represented in the form  as given in option(1) only...

Comment: @lulu:what is $d^2$ in your example?

Comment: I think you are misreading.  Surely it says something to the effect of "some, but not all,  $a$ which are expressible as $b^2+c^2$ can be written, etc."  My number, $5\times 13\times 17=1105$ , can not be written in any of the forms you list.

Comment: @lulu:you're correct about the  representation of $a$,but i think you ignored the "forms" of $p,q$ for example In example 1,we have to take into consideration only those primes $"p"$ ,which are of the form $p=4k+1$

Answer (score 1):

Due to the [Sum of two squares theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem) for (2), (3) and (4) you anyway would have the left side ($a$) to have a factor $p^{2k+1}$ in its prime decomposition. So (2), (3) and (4) cannot represent $a$.